# Getting "Could not get unknown property 'flutter' for extension 'android'" error in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my Flutter app in Android Studio. I'm receiving the following error message:

`A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Could not get unknown property 'flutter' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.`

Here's the content of my android/app/build.gradle file:

```
// ... (other configurations)

android {
    namespace "com.example.socializer"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    // ... (other configurations)

    defaultConfig {
        // ... (other configurations)
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    // ... (other configurations)
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

I've verified that my Flutter installation is correct, and my Flutter and Dart plugins are up to date in Android Studio. I've also checked the local.properties file for the correct Flutter SDK path.

However, I'm still encountering this error. Can anyone provide insights into why I'm facing this issue and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!